# img div not working on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This code looks nice when run on a desktop, but I want only one img showing on mobile. I only see `class="imgprice"` product text, and a very, very small img:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <p class="text-center">Here our products.</p>
    <?php    
    if(is_array($udvalg)) {    
        foreach($udvalg as $vare)
        {    
            echo '      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">';    
            echo '        <span class="thumbnail">';
            echo '<div class="imgprice">'.$vare->varenavn.'</div>';
            if ($vare->varefoto) {
                echo '            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/uploads/vare_foto/'.$vare->varefoto.'" alt="'.$vare->varenavn.'">';
            } else {    
                echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/uploads/vare_foto/polser.cb23b1.jpg" alt="'.$vare->varenavn.'">';
            }    
            echo '        </span>';    
            echo '      </div>';
        }}        
    ?>
</div>
```

I want a row of images on desktop, and 1 x 100% width image on mobile?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? 
Provide usable html + css (and js if youre using it) to see the error

Comment: i use : <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using custom CSS, you can achieve this with CSS's `@media` tag if you know the width of the mobile screen/width of the image, something like this:

```
@media(max-width={...}) { /* Replace ellipsis with your size */
    img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you're using a version of Bootstrap with `container-fluid`, you can try giving your image a `container-fluid` class. `container-fluid` has the following CSS on it according to the Bootstrap CSS ([here](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)):

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```